# Pagination in django API

Tags: python, django, api, video

I need help I am fetching movie data from the movie database so far everything good with the responses. But I am stack on the pagination Because it only returns 20 objects. And I want to return the other results when clicking on pagination buttons.

I have tried many ways But the only thing I can achieve is to return the results by passing the parameters
in the URL ej. ?page=2 returns another 20 objects ?page=3 returns 20 more objects.And I want to do that but with pagination buttons. I tried using Django pagination but it does not work as it only returns objects from my database and not API.

Here is my code in views. Also I am using a small library that I found on github but it does not have a documentation.

My code Here:

```
def peliculasPopulares(request):
tmdb = TMDb()
tmdb.language = 'es'
tmdb.api_key = 'my-api'
movie = Movie()
page = request.GET.get('page')
popular = movie.popular(page)


return render(request, 'peliculas/populares.html', {
    'title': 'populares',
    'populares': popular
})
```

Comment: without any parameter how django will know how many row to fetch and where to start?

Answer (score 0):

you could use django pagination which is also well documented, and if you need a good template, use this one:

```
{% with page.paginator.num_pages as total_pages and page.number as current_page %}
Total page{{ total_pages|pluralize }}: {{ total_pages }}

{% if current_page > 3 %}
    First
{% else %} {% endif %} {% for counter in page.paginator.page_range %} {% if forloop.first and counter < current_page|add:-2 %}
...
{% elif counter == current_page|add:-1 or counter == current_page|add:-2 %}
    {{ counter }}
{% elif counter == current_page and total_pages != 1 %}
    {{ counter }}
{% elif current_page < counter and counter <= current_page|add:2 %}
    {{ counter }}
{% elif counter > current_page|add:2 and forloop.last %}
    ...
{% endif %} {% endfor %} {% if page.has_next and current_page|add:2 < total_pages %}
    Last
{% comment %} {% else %}
Last
{% endcomment %} {% endif %}
{% endwith %} {% block extra_heads %} {% endblock extra_heads %}
```

Comment: not sure weather the questioner understands this, but what you are showing is what we use in class based views. but he is using functional views.

Comment: actually I used what I said, in function based views. also the template was created for function based.

Comment: Thank but like I said I already tried using the Django pagination but I can get it work for what I want. The movie database is showing only 20 objects by default. If I use the pagination.. For example if I assign 12 objects by page it only returns 2 pages 1 page with 12 objects and the second one with 8 objects because it's only counting the 20 objects that the movie database return for page.

Comment: so, I couldn't understand the problem of this 12 items page